# Fake an address from my browser / metamask

Tags: metamask, wallets, javascript

I want to use a website as an ethereum address that I don't control, so I can get calldata for some specific transaction(s) from that address.

In my chrome JS console, I can do `window.ethereum._handleAccountsChanged(['0xabc...'])` but that only seems to last for a second or so, and when I interact with any page to trigger a transaction, MetaMask switches back to my real account.

I understand that I won't be able to broadcast valid transactions since I don't have the signing key, but I want to use mock addresses to get valid merkle proofs for addresses that I don't control.

Answer (score 4):

I found https://impersonator.xyz, which accomplishes what I'm looking for as long as the site is compatible with WalletConnect.